# Custom Route overruling Nova route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-nova

I have an issue, I can't seem to fix using Nova as the backend for an editorial site. I renamed the path from /nova to /backend via the config which worked perfectly.

Now my frontend requires a very general routing structure as most of the logic is placed in the controller, giving the user some additional flexibility.

As soon as I add these routes to my web routes, the backend goes to a 404. Obviously, my second rule matches the /backend and since there is no page by that name within my database, it fails.

What can I do to assure that Nova's routes are parsed first, or that the /backend requests are ignored by my routes?

Laravel v5.7. Tried the usual tricks - php artisan config:clear, php artisan route:clear - as well as adding a regex to the route:

```
->where('seite', '^(?!backend).*$');
```

Current web route file:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@frontPage');
Route::get('/{seite}/{zweit?}/{dritt?}', 'PagesController@anyPage');
```

/backend should be handled by Nova, not my custom route.

Comment: Could you share your `config/app.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end it was this that did the trick:

```
->where('seite', '^(?!backend).*$');
```

In my previous attempts to get it to work I must have broken something else. I did a clean reinstall of Laravel in Nova, moved over my files and added the regex and it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with generic slugs in my routes file. I managed to limit the pattern for the slugs to alpha-numeric characters (including dashes, hyphens and slashes*) but exclude the Nova routes (`nova-api` and `nova-vendor`) as well as the custom Nova path (`backend`).

This is how the `routes/web.php` file looks like:

```php
Route::get('/{seite}', 'PageController@anyPage');
```

And the pattern in the `RouteServiceProvider` in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('seite', '^(?!backend|nova-api|nova-vendor).[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+$');

    parent::boot();
}
```

*) Please note that this pattern also allows slugs like `/seite/zweit/drei` as shown in the question above.